# PHP on WAMP preferring same random array elements?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, random, wamp

I am new to PHP and AJAX, and as a test I tried to create a script that gets the name of a random image in a folder on my server. However, it seems that the server prefers to give only names that it has already given. That is, it appears that, given that an file name has already been received once by the client, it is more likely to appear again later on the client. This, of course, it not the intended functionality. I suspect it has something to do with caching, but, as I mentioned before, I am not incredibly well-versed in using PHP.

The following is the script that gets the random file name:

```
<?php
$dir = "../img";
$files = array_values(array_diff(scandir($dir),["..",".",".htaccess"]));
$file = $files[array_rand($files)];
echo $file;
?>
```

Changing the script to use `echo array_rand($files)` seems to verify that the random numbers are, indeed, biased.

I have also read that PHP does poor random number generation on Windows. If this is why this is happening, is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function can indeed have strange issues with it's "randomness".

You can try to run shuffle on the array before selecting a random entry:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

But I would recommend using PHP's mt_rand function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

It's a newer, better solution for selecting random values.  You'll need to set the max and min values:

```
$array = scandir();
$random = mt_rand(0, (count($array) - 1));
$random_element = $array[$random];
```

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: It's not perfect, but it's definitely better. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, you'll find there are always some issues trying to use random programatically. random.org has a decent API you could look into. Also, I've updated my answer to change the max for mt_rand() to (count($array) - 1) since arrays are 0-indexed.